# Problems with overloading voids/adding optional parameters in Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, overloading

We've been coping with this issue for quite some time and find only half useful solutions.

Our main method in Web Service application called "MainVoid" needs to have additional parameter for example:

MainVoid (before):

```
 public void MainVoid (string Parameter1, int Parameter2, bool Parameter 3)
```

Into (MainVoid (before)):

```
public void Main Void (string Parameter1, int Parameter2, bool Parameter 3, int Parameter4)
```

We have few application which used this void but we don't want to rebuild/republish all. The ideal scenario would be that old applications would call void with one parameter less, whereas "new" applications would could the same void but with one parameter more.

As I know, unfortunately using optional parameters is not possible in WCF which is quite a big issue.

Then we tried to overload functions bellow

```
[OperationContract]
```

With similar approach to this: [overloading methods in web service](http://www.a2zmenu.com/Blogs/WCF/WCF%20Service%20Method%20Overloading.aspx)

Debugging Web Service works fine (if no parameter is passed then optional parameter default value is inserted).
In other project which calls the WebService the Intellisense finds overloaded methods (it offers 2 options, instead of one).

But when we run debug on the application which is calling web service the debugger wants all parameters so it throws an error.

Sorry for such a long post but I've tried to explain our problem as best as possible. The second approach demands changing of reference files in other projects so it's not a wanted solution.

Guess there is no other way than creating 2 voids with different name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using different names would at the very least be *clearer* IMO. Overloading has enough oddities even within plain C#, without any optional parameters or web service bits going on.

Another alternative is to change the web service to use a custom parameter type, and add more information to that parameter type over time.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. Do you maybe have some example for 2nd advice?

Answer (score 0):

How about defining the new parameter as a nullable datatype (i.e. `int?`) and checking for `Parameter4 == null` or `Parameter4.HasValue` within the method implementation?

You would then only need one method.

Comment: I'v also try with nullable type like: (int? parameter = 0) but Web Service wasn't happy with this either. It demanded one more parameter if it was missing in function. I think I will go with Jon Skeet solution. We have several projects which must not be stopped because in some error in web service. However I've thought this would be easier.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  I did try this approach and was able to send a message from both an "old" and a "new" client without a problem.  I did not use a default, though.  I defined the parameter as simply `int? parameter` instead of `int? parameter = 0`.  I'm not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: I've tried with int? parameter = 0 and DateTime parameter = DateTime.Now and had no luck although we are using .NET 4.0 framework.I think that int? means that default value is null, whereas int? = 0 means that default value is 0. But I'm not 100% for the first  case...